# Limit of a Function involving tangent function and limits at infinity

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Determine $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\tan{\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$.

**Attempt**

Let $$y=\left(\tan{\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$

Put $\frac{1}{x}=p$.

$$\lim_{p \to 0}\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)^p$$.

We have 
 $$\lim_{x \to \infty} y=\lim_{p \to 0}\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)^p$$.

Now consider the function $y$ in variable $p$ 
Taking $ln$ both sides
$$ln\left(y\right)=p.ln\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)$$.
$$ln\left(y\right)=p.\frac{ln\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)}{\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}}.\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}$$.

Putting $\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}=m$

We have

$$ln\left(y\right)=p.\frac{ln\left(m\right)}{m}.\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}$$.

As $x \to \infty$ we have $p \to 0$ and hence $m \to \infty$

Hence the limit of $\frac{ln\left(m\right)}{m}$ is $0$.

But I am unable to show the limit of other to part of the product.
Please help me out.

Comment: The definition of $y$ is inconsistent. Also, what sort of manipulation is it after that???

Comment: @RakeshBhatt Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi why should I accept if my doubt has not been resolved yet. I was supposed to give my attempt so that-"it is easier for others to judge the most appropriate "level" for an answer to my question if I provide these attempts. So I'll receive answers better suited to my specific needs." But it doesn't meet my need.   It does not help me with my attempt and my Idea

Comment: Indeed you are not forced to accept if any answer fulfill your OP, I will take a look to it again. Thanks

Comment: Note that with your attempt when $p\to 0$ we have that $m\to \pi/2$.

Comment: @gimusi your reasoning is wrong with $p \to 0$, we have $m\to \tan\frac{\pi}{2}=\infty$

Comment: @Suraj ops sorru I've lost the tan, I will take a loog again! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\left(\tan{\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}\right)^\frac{1}{x}=\left(\tan{\frac{\pi x+\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\pi}2}{2x+1}}\right)^\frac{1}{x}=\left(\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\frac{\pi}2}{2x+1}\right)}\right)^\frac{1}{x}=\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{x}}=e^{-\frac{\log{\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}\right)}}{x}}\to 1$$

Indeed

$$-\frac{\log{\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}\right)}}{x}=-\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}\right)\log{\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}\right)}\frac{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}{\tan{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}}\frac{\frac{4x+2}{\pi}}{x}\to0\cdot1\cdot \frac4 \pi=0$$

As an alternative, according to the change of variable $p=\frac 1 x \to 0$, from here

$$\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)^p=e^{p\log \left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)}\to 1$$

indeed

$$p\log \left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)=p\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\frac{\log \left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)}{\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}}\to 0$$

indeed

$$\frac{\log \left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)}{\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}}\to 0$$
$$p\tan{\frac{\pi}{2+p}}=\frac{p}{\tan\left({\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\pi}{2+p}}\right)}=\frac{p}{\tan\left({\frac{\pi p}{2p+4}}\right)}=\frac{\frac{\pi p}{2p+4}}{\tan\left({\frac{\pi p}{2p+4}}\right)}\frac{2p+4}{\pi}\to \frac 4 \pi$$

Comment: Thanks for solution..It seems correct but I Cannot understand your solution..It no where continuation of my solution...can't move ahead with my Idea!

Comment: You can use the same method also after the change $p=1/x$ even if it is not necessary. Which step is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

With $t:=1/x\to0$,
$$\left(\tan\frac\pi{2+t}\right)^t=\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\frac\pi {2+t}\right)\right)^{-t}=\left(\tan\frac{\pi t}{2(2+t)}\right)^{-t}$$

is asymptotic to $(\frac\pi4t)^{-t}$ and tends to $1$.

Comment: When x goes to infinity 1/x tends to 0, now whatever the value of limit of $\tan$ is $lim (\tan ..)^0 =1$

Comment: @sirous: no, $(\tan t^{1/t})^t$ would tend to $0$, for instance.

Comment: Unwelcome silent downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use asymptotic expansions.

$$y=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}\right)^{1/x}$$

As $x\to\infty$,
$\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}\approx \pi/2$

For $h$ near to $\pi/2$,
$$\sin(h)\approx 1$$
$$\cos(h)\approx \pi/2-h$$
$$\tan(h)\approx \frac1{\pi/2-h}$$

Thus,
$$\tan( \frac{\pi x}{2x+1})\approx \frac1{\pi/2-\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}=\frac2\pi(2x+1)$$

$$\ln y\approx \frac{\ln \frac2\pi(2x+1)}x\to 0$$

So, $y=1$.

Comment: That way can be a good method for a first estimation but you should need to make it more rigorous to prove the limit.

Comment: @gimusi Actually they are asymptotic expansions and can be rigorously justified. I used the approximation sign simply because Math SE somehow doesn’t allow me to type ~.

Answer (score 0):

$$L =\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\tan{\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\tan{\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{2 + 4 x}{\pi}\right)\tag{1}$$
So
$$L = e^{\left(\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x}\ln(g(x))\right)}$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2 + 4 x}{\pi}\right)}{x}\right) \stackrel{I´H}{\implies} \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{2}{2x + 1}\right) = 0$$
Therefore
$$L = e^0 = 1$$

---

**(1) Proof :**

For $x \to\infty$
$$g(x) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}\right) =\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1 }{\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}\right)}\right) =\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1 }{\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}\right) } - \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1 }{\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}\right) } - 1\right) + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}- \frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x+1 }\right)\right)$$

Set $\frac{1}{\left(2x+1\right) } = t$, observe that, as $t \to 0$
$$
\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}t\right) 
= \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-t)\right) = \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}t\right) = \frac{\cos(\pi t) +1 }{\sin(\pi t)}=\\
\end{align}$$

$$\frac{\pi t}{\pi t}\cdot\frac{\cos(\pi t) +1 }{\sin(\pi t)}=$$
$$\frac{1}{t\pi}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{\pi t }{\sin(\pi t)}\left(\cos(\pi t) +1\right)\right)}_{t \to 0 \implies 2}=
\frac{1}{t\pi}\cdot 2 = $$
$$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\left(2x+1\right)}\right)\pi}\cdot 2 =
\frac{(2 + 4 x)}{\pi}\tag*{$\Box$}$$